# How to implement occlusion in Autodesk Forge issues sample?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I would like to implement issue system like this sample

https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/

In this sample, issues are not occluded when I see them from the opposite side.

How can you implement occlusion in this issue sample?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific sample the issues are displayed as simple `<div>` elements overlaid on top of the 3D viewport, and so they *cannot* be occluded by the 3D content.

If occlusion is critical for you, you could insert custom annotations *into the 3D scene* as explained in this blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! The sample project in the blog post is using Raycaster and PointCloud. On the other hand, there are some APIs called Scene builder and viewer.overlay (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/). Which is more suitable to achieve the issues which can be occluded?

Comment: `viewer.overlay` is used for rendering content that is *not* occluded (for example, the selection highlight) so I would not recommend using that one. `SceneBuilder` is a better option, or simply add content to `viewer.impl.scene` or `viewer.impl.sceneAfter` as the blog post suggests.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I will choose one the two: PointCloud approach or SceneBuilder approach.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Can you check if an object is occluded when using SceneBuilder approach? I would like to show issues only when objects related to the issues are not occluded.

Comment: Unfortunately the viewer does not provide any way of checking whether a specific design element is occluded or not.

Comment: You can take advantage of [sprites](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/) to handle occlusion.